# Are these theme folder paths equivalent? Place theme in /vendor/?

Tags: magento2, theme-fallback

```
/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/
```

&&

```
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/
```

Am I correct to assume /vendor/ is always the fallback from app?

If that is true, could I install my theme to:

```
/vendor/joshua34/theme-frontend-mytheme/
```

Does theme registration or another issue prevent theme installation here?

DevDocs states Magento themes can be installed under /vendor/, ["when a Magento instance is deployed from the Composer repository."](http://%22when%20a%20Magento%20instance%20is%20deployed%20from%20the%20Composer%20repository.%22)

What about custom themes not installed via composer?

Answer (score 1):

You can place you theme in any folder. Only one requirement is register it in \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar